# cannot display crystal report on aplication asp.net Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

i tried to use crystal report on visual studio 2012, and it doesn't show the report on it. do i missing something? this is my code on visual studio:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
    <Report FileName="Report\Report.rpt">
    </Report>
</CR:CrystalReportSource>
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
```

Comment: post error you getting

Comment: installed CR runtime engine ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I'm not install that. how can I check that?

Comment: can you find crystal report in toolbox? able to preview while programming ? can you find crystal report viewer in toolbox ? no debug errors?